# How to add syntax highlighting to indented code blocks using github flavored markdown

Tags: github, markdown

Using github flavored markdown, there are three sytnax variants for a block of code:

1. [**Fenced code blocks**](https://github.github.com/gfm/#fenced-code-blocks)

   ````
   ```js
   var user = "string"
   ```
   ````
2. [**Indented code blocks**](https://github.github.com/gfm/#indented-code-blocks)

   ```
       var user = "string"
   ```
3. [**Html blocks**](https://github.github.com/gfm/#html-blocks) <sup>[example 137](https://github.github.com/gfm/#example-137)</sup>

   ```
   <pre><code>var user = <i>"string"</i>
   </code></pre>
   ```

Github will also apply [syntax highlighting](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks/) when parsing markdown files, but I can't get it to work for indented or html blocks.

How can I tell github to run syntax highlighting or even specify a language for indented code blocks or html code blocks?

#### [Here's a gist with a working demo of github's markdown parsing](https://gist.github.com/KyleMit/7296968615a3cb54d0b5688bbf9d96b7)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [GitHub Flavored Markdown Spec](https://github.github.com/gfm/#html-block) it says:

> The line with the opening code fence may optionally contain some text
>   following the code fence; this is trimmed of leading and trailing
>   whitespace and called the info string. (...) The content of a code
>   fence is treated as literal text, not parsed as inlines. The first
>   word of the info string is typically used to specify the language of
>   the code sample, and rendered in the class attribute of the code tag.

And *earlier* it also says:

> An indented code block has no info string.

So I think it's not possible to embed language information in indented
code blocks. To put language information inside HTML block I found
this to be working ok:

```
<pre lang="javascript"><code>var user = "string"
</code></pre>
```

Here is a short test on Github:
https://gist.github.com/ardrabczyk/179e05e0a2134389de3d270c2a10ee26

Comment: Oh, sweet!!  I'm a sucker for throwing samples inside `<pre><code>` blocks and escaping myself so I can throw in some extra `<b>` or `<i>` tags to empahsize sections within the code.  This'll help bunches.  Thanks!

Comment: Ahh, definitely answers the question, but didn't happen to solve my roundabout problem.  Now that syntax highlighting is being applied to html blocks, it's sanitizing the tags inside them